# sidebar is behaving unexpected when order changes wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my index.php code

```
<?php get_header() ; ?>

<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) { ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> <!-- .container -->
<?php get_footer() ; ?>
```

which works fine when the order of sidebar is like
category
recent posts
search
(see image)

[image]

but when sidebar order changes to

search
category
recent posts

it looks like very differently ( see image)

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm - looks like unbalanced tags. Could we see the online page? I would also check the plugins you use (or even your theme) as I suspect someone's using a WordPress filter to do something, and maybe not close their html tags correctly.

Comment: https://wordstrap-cannelflow1.c9users.io

Comment: editor link https://ide.c9.io/cannelflow1/wordstrap

Comment: Thanks - indeed, unbalanced tags. I think it might be your search widget. Which widget did you use for this? Any plugins installed? Did you customize your theme?

Comment: actually learning theme development  only two plugin is there akismet and hello dolly went to appearance > widgets then dragged search bar to sidebar

Comment: Ok - and in your theme, is there a sidebar.php file? If so, what's in it? And in your functions.php file, how do you register your sidebars?

Comment: there is no sidebar.php for now my functions.php looks like https://gist.github.com/cannelflow/8865fe28094f7b172ed1992a6e529cdc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link to your functions.php file. That is where your problem lies: (lines 67-68)

```
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-module %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div></div></div>',
```

See how you open the widget with one  tag, but you close it with three? Try this instead:

```
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-module %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
```

Hope this helps!